# Adding processing 3 to a Jpanel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, processing

I am trying to show a processing 3 sketch inside a Jpanel from a swing application window. (I am using eclipse) please help!

I need the complexity and features of a swing based GUI and also want the user friendliness of processing to create visual content in my application.

I have used Kevin's very helpful answer and created a more specific question. Thanks Kevin!

I want the processing sketch to be a subclass that is called from MainGUI.java and inserted into a JPanel. The problem I am having is eclipse is saying pt.initSurface() is not visible.

Thanks again for your help.

MainGUI.java

```
import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT;
import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PSurface;
import processing.opengl.*;
import processing.data.*;
import processing.event.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import patterns.ProcessingTest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MainGUI {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainGUI window = new MainGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainGUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(52, 24, 110, 143);

        //create your sketch
        ProcessingTest pt = new ProcessingTest();

        //get the PSurface from the sketch
        PSurface ps = pt.initSurface();

        //initialize the PSurface
        ps.setSize(200, 200);

        //get the SmoothCanvas that holds the PSurface
        SmoothCanvas smoothCanvas = (SmoothCanvas)ps.getNative();

        panel.setSize(200, 200);

         //SmoothCanvas can be used as a Component
        panel.add(smoothCanvas);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        //start your sketch
        ps.startThread();

    }
}
```

ProcessingTest.java

```
package patterns;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PSurface;

public class ProcessingTest extends PApplet{

    public void settings(){
        size(200, 200);
    }

    public void draw(){
        background(0);
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm I wonder if including what has not worked for you, might be helpful in narrowing down what will work for you...

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question. Please note that it is a **[tag:processing]** question, not a purely Java question. Processing 2 had the ability to embed itself into a `JFrame`. Processing 3 removed that ability, and it can be very confusing. This is a perfectly valid Processing question, and people have closed it because it sounds like a vague Java question. It's not. It's a specific Processing question.

Answer (score 10):

In Processing 2, `PApplet` extended `Applet`, so you could embed it in an `AWT` or `Swing` `Component` like `JPanel`.

As of Processing 3, `PApplet` no longer extends `Applet`, so you can no longer embed it as a `Component`.

That being said, you have three options:

**Option 1:** Are you really sure you need to embed your Processing sketch?

Think about exactly why you need to embed your Processing sketch. Is there a way around it? You can write GUI code in Processing using [one of these GUI libraries](https://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/#gui).

You could also create a separate `JFrame` from Processing.

**Option 2:** Do you just need to launch your Processing sketch from Java?

If so, you can simply call the `PApplet.main("YourSketchNameHere")` function. This will tell Processing to start up your sketch, and Processing will handle the creation of your window, calling `setup()`, and starting the `draw()` loop for you.

Here's a little example that can be run from eclipse:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class ProcessingTest extends PApplet{

    public void settings(){
        size(200, 200);
    }

    public void draw(){
        background(0);
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        PApplet.main("ProcessingTest");
    }
}
```

**Option 3:** Are you really, really, really sure you need to embed your `PApplet`?

If the first two options don't work, then you can still get to the underlying component. Processing 3 introduced a `PSurface` class, and this class contains the component. To embed your sketch, you have to get its `PSurface`, then you have to get the native component from the `PSurface`. This isn't exactly straightforward, but it's doable:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PSurface;

public class ProcessingTest extends PApplet{

    public void settings(){
        size(200, 200);
    }

    public void draw(){
        background(0);
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
    }

    public static void main(String... args){

        //create your JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //create your sketch
        ProcessingTest pt = new ProcessingTest();

        //get the PSurface from the sketch
        PSurface ps = pt.initSurface();

        //initialize the PSurface
        ps.setSize(200, 200);

        //get the SmoothCanvas that holds the PSurface
        SmoothCanvas smoothCanvas = (SmoothCanvas)ps.getNative();

        //SmoothCanvas can be used as a Component
        frame.add(smoothCanvas);

        //make your JFrame visible
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //start your sketch
        ps.startThread();
    }
}
```

Once you have the native component, you can treat it like you would any other Swing component.

Note that you have to know ahead of time what type of native component will be returned from the `PSurface.getNative()` function. This depends on which renderer you're using. The default renderer uses `SmoothCanvas`, but other renderers use other native components.

Also note that you have to inititalize and start your sketch.

You should use one of the first two options if at all possible, but if you really really need to embed your sketch, then option 3 is available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin some great points that really helped me understand my problem. It is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. I have a better understanding of how to ask questions and navigate the website now. I edited my question based on your answer. It should be more informative and specific. Thanks

Comment: Option3 is totally doable. Everyone who says embedding the canvas within a jframe is not possible with processing3 is not correct.